# echoing document.getElementById() with php variable as id

Tags: php, echo

Hi I have a list of buttons with different id's like b_1, b_2, b_3 and so on. After that I have PHP code to interact with the database and get my results.
Then I have created a variable that receives the identity of the rows that it finds in the table. I would like to use the result to change the background color of the different buttons. It works fine if I write the literal identity "b_1" or "b_2" and so on but not in the form of a variable ($trans_boton).
I have tried in many ways and I can't find the key. Thanks for lighting.

```
$trans_boton = 'b_'.$data['numero'];

if($facta == $respuesta){
echo "<script>"; echo "document.getElementById('b_1').style.backgroundColor='red';"; echo "</script>";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put $trans_boton in quotes, ie:

```
echo "document.getElementById('$trans_boton')" ;
```

Comment: The $trans_boton variable already has the composite value, only that for some reason the execution produced errors.
If you remove the extra code you wrote from your comment then I can put it as the correct answer. After all it was only about what you said although I had already tried it and it resulted in an error. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I removed the extra code -- I was hard-coding the value and printing it out just for testing purposes to show that it worked by itself, since I didn't have the rest of your code which declared $trans_boton.